# Always Restart when Clicking Shut Down Button

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, restart

When I shutdown the computer (Ubuntu 14.04), it always retart. Sometime when I press shutdown in the menu, the computer does not show me the mini window for the shutdown button.

How to fix it?

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: This is my biggest nuisance with Ubuntu at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar issue in 12.04, and luckily it is already answered here in askubuntu here:

[Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)

Basically you have to change some parameters on the grub entry of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, but if you just want to shut down your PC type

init 0 (for shutdown)
Init 6 (for restarting the system )

You must be root or use "sudo"