# Ubuntu 17.10 Windows 10 Dual Boot PC (HP Pavilion 15) gets corrupted disk and needs system restore. Cures anyone?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I successfully dual booted Ubuntu 17.10 (latest stable) and Windows 10 (latest version) - buy that man a drink, I hear you say, because that was far from easy!

I could always boot up Ubuntu as long as I didn't EVER try to re-boot Windows. If I ran Windows then the system became corrupt and eventually I had to back-up my Windows 10 to external hard disk (I never ever want to do this again)! Then re-install everything and start again to make my PC dual boot - this is where I am now. Scared to boot into Windows in case the disk is corrupted. I can happily repeatedly re-boot into Ubuntu though via Grub2 and my Windows 10 is installed alongside.BUT if I let Windows boot by default i.e. system restart but don't activate Grub2 just let default boot up occur - that always starts Windows 10 even if I don't want it to!

So, any ideas on how to prevent the disk corruption so that I can happily dual boot either system AND safely choose the system and the default boot system?

I could supply more and more detail but until I have some means of progressing the problem I will hold my tongue. I don't know as yet what information is relevant to getting at the problem.

Thanks in advance etc... Dave

Comment: 1) did you shrink  the windows partition from within windows? 2) Is hibernate and Fast Start disabled in windows?

Comment: In addition to ravery's comment this question is also worth considering: [Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)