# Complications With Dual Boot Of Ubuntu and Windows 8 UEFI

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have been all over the entire askubuntu.com trying to find a solution to my present issue but none has brought any joy, so I gave up and just had to post this.

I have an HP Envy M6 pre-installed with Windows 8 and HP's recovery bloatware, I couldn't survive without Ubuntu and decided to set it up, I got everything set up with a Live CD, created the right partitions and did everything I was supposed to do and then restarted my pc.

As expected, being a UEFI-based pc, I didn't expect to see a grub menu on next startup without some tinkering, so I decided to get EasyBCD, an app that worked fine on my custom built Desktop, I created the Ubuntu entry in the app and got a boot menu after restarting my PC, and tried booting into Ubuntu, then got  a nasty error that some `Autoneogrub.mbr` was corrupted or missing, fine, I came back online to seek help and found out EasyBCD doesn't support new UEFI boards.

Then I ventured into the wild, (I couldn't Boot Into Ubuntu yet),  I started reading up on how I could get back grub on a UEFI pc that would boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu fine, then I came across the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file). I attempted to boot into Ubuntu from the partion created by choosing to boot from the Ubuntu partition on startup and then perfromed the steps in that answer.

I was able to get grub on startup with the `Windows Boot Loader(dev/sda2)` entry, but surprisingly I keep getting thrown back into grub, no errors, just grub showing up again, I decided to boot into Ubuntu and reverted back to the state of my `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot` directory before I performed the former step , and Windows booted again without any Boot Menu's.

I have tried installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind) and boot-repair in Ubuntu to fix this issue but they didn't help, I didn't even get a refind boot manager, neither did boot-repair, so currently the only way I've been able to boot into Ubuntu is by choosing advanced startup in Windows and then selecting to boot from Ubuntu's partitions.

I think HP's EFI might be behind all this, cause I read so many tutorials on dual-booting Ubuntu on a UEFI-based Pc and they were all okay.

Comment: Possibly related to [Ubuntu doesn't provide \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI for UEFI systems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1366546) and http://askubuntu.com/a/510172/40581 hopfully this helps you fix your problem.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence. I would be more specific and say that the UEFI implementation of this model is at fault, not generally HP. I see more of such issues where consumer orientend models only boot `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` and thus only booting Windows and OSes that provide this binary and disregard booting NVRAM entries. I don't know why the market moves into this direction, possibly to reduce complexity, but I recall watching a video of an HP engineer at a Linux conference a few years back talkig about UEFI, stating they were deeply involved with EFI back in IA64 days.

Answer (score 1):

When installing any OS on an UEFI based computer and GPT disk
installation source - USB/DVD - should be booted the UEFI way.

Nothing more.

Ubuntu GRUB can chainload Windows on BIOS and UEFI.
Windows boot manager can chainload GRUB/Ubuntu only on BIOS/MBR.

[BootNext](http://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html) utility can boot Ubuntu/Linux directly from Windows.